# using awk to print if any three variables are true

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, variable

I want the code print if any of these variables are true.
this is not my real code, it's just an example

```
read -p "enter protocol: " protocol
read -p "enter src ip: " srcip
read -p "enter dst ip: " dstip
read -p "enter src port: " srcport 
read -p "enter dst port: " dstport
```

and so on

```
awk -F"," -v pro="$protocol" -v sip="$srcip" -v dip="$dstip" -v sport="$srcport"  -v dport="$dstport" '{ if(pro == "tcp" && sip == "10" && dip == "30" && sport == "4" && dport == "1") 
print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' test.txt > test2.txt
```

I will write it here by another way for more clarification

```
PROTOCOL,SRC IP,SRC PORT,DEST IP,DEST port
tcp      .10     29      .30     300
udp      .34     545     .94    90
tcp      .23     233     .23    42
```

I need any three of these variables matching with user inputs, print the line.

I have tried the below code but give me an error.

```
awk -F","  -v pro="$protocol" -v sip="$srcip" -v dip="$dstip" -v sport="$srcport"  -v dport="$dstport" 'BEGIN {if ($3 ~ pro) count++; if ($4 ~ sip) count++; if ($5 == sport) count++; if ($6 ~ dip) count++; if ($7 == dport) count++; count>=3; { print  $3,$4,$5,$6,$7 }' test.txt > test2.txt
error: ^ syntax error 
      ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

Comment: Should we assume `$a`, `$b` etc. are _shell variables_?  If so, couldn't you do the test in the shell and then run your pipeline if the condition is met?  It would be better to see an actual, real example.

Comment: okay i will edit it now with real example

Comment: If you want awk to use shell variables, you need to pass the variables into the awk program like this: `awk -F, -v sip=$sip ... '{ if (sip==50 ... }'`, since the single quotes prevent the shell from replacing the variables by their values.

Comment: i already using it, but forget to mention here, but do you have know the way to solved my issue

Comment: You are already using what? In order to make your example work: `awk -F, -v sip="$sip" -v dip="$dip" -v srcport="$srcport" -v d="$d" -v e="$e" '{ if (sip==50 &&  dip==50 && srcport==30 && d==4 && e==1 ) print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7 }' test.txt > test2.txt`. It would be simpler to perform the test outside of awk, e.g. `if [[ "$sip" == 50 && (I think you guess the rest) ]]; then awk -F '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, %6, $7}' test.txt > test2.txt`.

Comment: By the way, don't use `cat` in this way. `awk` is perfectly capable to read from a file; no need to force it to read from standard input. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat.

Comment: @berndbausch yes bro, i already edited the code, but my question how can i make if any three of these inputs are true then print, must be three inputs are truee!

Comment: To test if any of the three is true, use "or" `||` instead of "and" `&&`. Both for awk and Bash code.

Comment: @berndbausch no bro, i want any three of the total variables not any of the three. i want if three variables are true from the total then print

Comment: My first solution is a logical AND: If all conditions are true, print. My second solution is a logical OR: If any condition is true, print. I understand that you don't want either, but I don't understand what you want. What do you mean by "total"?

Comment: @berndbausch i mean like my example above i have these variables (PROTOCOL,SRC IP,SRC PORT,DEST IP,DEST port) i want if any three of these variables are true then print, but must be three true

Comment: You mean at least three must be true? If that is so, then count. For example in Bash: `count=0; if [[ $sip == 50 ]]; then count=$((count+1)); fi ... if [[ $count >= 3 ]] then awk ...; fi`. Or entirely in AWK: `BEGIN { if (sip==50) count++; if (srcport=30) count++; ...} count>=3 { print ... }`. It can probably be done more elegantly.

Comment: @berndbausch could you please give me the full code as i tried both but always give me an error

Comment: I don't know the full requirements. Add your code and the error to the question.

Comment: @berndbausch i add my code and error to the question. Thanks

Comment: first issue is that you should not use BEGIN block here, and since you used, but you didn't close the block with `}` (cause of that error). But you need write your code like `awk -F","  -v pro="$protocol" -v sip="$srcip" -v dip="$dstip" -v sport="$srcport"  -v dport="$dstport" '{if ($3 ~ pro) count++; if ($4 ~ sip) count++; if ($5 == sport) count++; if ($6 ~ dip) count++; if ($7 == dport) count++} count>=3{ print  $3,$4,$5,$6,$7 }' test.txt` (I added no improvements, just error fix); and **STOP** responding in the comments, instead **[edit]** your question.

Comment: @peterlouis αғsнιη pointed out your problem with braces. Note that your program doesn't quite correspond to your original request, but I hope you know what you are doing. Differences: You use `~` instead of `==` in some places, and instead of comparing the variables `pro`, `sip` etc to constants, you compare them to fields in the input file. I included a BEGIN clause in my version assuming you needed constants.

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
awk -F',' -v pro="$protocol" -v sip="$srcip" -v dip="$dstip" -v sport="$srcport" -v dport="$dstport" '
    {
        c = 0
        c += (pro == "tcp")
        c += (sip == "10")
        c += (dip == "30")
        c += (sport == "4")
        c += (dport == "1")
    }
    c > 2
' test.txt
```

Make it `c > 2 { print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7 }` if you really want to only print that subset of fields instead of the whole line.

Comment: not working with me!

Comment: @peterlouis It would be _nice_ if you could say something about what happens when you try this, and in what particular way it's not working.

Comment: @peterlouis "it's not working" is the worst possible problem statement as it gives us asbolutely no information to debug the problem. Always say in what way anything is "not working" - wrong output, not output, syntax error, other error messages, core dump, etc.

Comment: I noticed a missing `)` in the code which would have been giving you a syntax error so I just fixed that. Is that the problem that made it "not working" for you?

Comment: @peterlouis does this answer work for you now? If not, let us know in what way it's failing but if so then see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "enter the src ip:" srcip
read -p "enter the des ip:"  desip
read -p "enter the src port:" srcport


awk -v srcip="$srcip" -v desip="$desip" -v srcport="$srcport" '($2 == srcip||$4 == desip || $5 == srcport){print $0}' filename
```

Tested and worked fine

output

enter the src ip:.10
enter the des ip:.30
enter the src port:34

tcp      .10     29      .30     300

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but actually i have more variables like i added now in my port not only three, so i want if any three of these variables are true, then print

Comment: Welcome  you can modify script above as per requirement please vote if its helped u

Comment: What this script does (test if 1 of 3 conditions is true) is not the problem the OP is trying to solve (test if any 3 of N conditions are true) and it's no closer to the solution than the script in the question that the OP started with.